# Sed is unable to copy temporary file to original file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

My aim is to edit the file(Whose owner is user1) using script where user2 don't have permission to directly edit the file but it should be edited when executed through script by user2, so I set SUID on the script
My script has below content

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter variable a"
read a
echo "Enter path"
read Path
echo "Enter variable b"
read b
sed -i -c "/#Hello variable \<$a\>/{h;n;s/\$Initial_Value=.*/\$Initial_Value=$b/}" "$Path"
```

Script replaces some matching pattern in the file provided as input

Permissions of the script are as follows

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 user1 user1 648 Jul 21 08:03 Script.ksh
```

Permissions of the file which script modifies are as follows

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user1 user1 224 Jul 21 10:46 file
```

Permissions of the directory under which the file is present  are as follows

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 user1 group1 122880 Jul 22 11:17 directory
```

Script is getting executed by user2 who is part of group1 where the file exists, and executing user2 will not have permissions to directly edit the file.

To edit the file indirectly using script I have set SUID bit on the script, thought that when executed by user2 it will get executed with the permissions of user1
But when I am executing the script SED is giving below error.

```
sed: cannot copy Path/sedFKvRSo to Path/file: Permission denied
```

Comment: Take a look at: [Allow setuid on shell scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/74329)

Answer (score 0):

Suid bit has no effects on interpreted scripts. Just enter the `id` command in it to find it out. Better edit the sudoers file, to allow user2 to run this script as root, or write a simple suid-wrapper for running it, as shown in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts).

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setuid(0);
    setgid(0);
    seteuid(0);
    setegid(0);
    execv("/tmp/script.sh", argv); // run the script
    return 0;
}
```